# Getting a list of the repeated last form data when trying to fetch the list of objects from database

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, controller, modelattribute

My first jsp is email.jsp and from there it is directed to template.jsp but when I try to get the list of EmailMessages object, I get repeated entries of the last form submitted data when I must be getting all the objects the database. Can anyone please help me through this?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/email", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String addEmail() {
    return "email";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/template", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String getTemplateEmail(@ModelAttribute EmailMessage emailMessage, ModelMap model) {
    emailService.insertTemplate(emailMessage);
    List<EmailMessage> emailMessageList = new ArrayList<EmailMessage>();
    emailMessageList = emailService.fetchTemplate();
    model.addAttribute("emailMessageList", emailMessageList);
    return "template";
}
```

email.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Email body</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/TemplateEmail/template" method="POST">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><b>Category </b>: </td>
        <td><select name="category">
            <option value=""> </option>
            <option value="normal">Normal</option>
            <option value="urgent">Urgent</option>
        </select></td>
        <td>
        <button type="button" style="width: 25px;height: 25px;border: solid 1px #000;border-radius: 25px" onclick="addCategory()">+</button>
        <script>
            function addCategory() {
                var category = prompt("Add new category", "");
            }
        </script>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>Subject </b>: </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="subject"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>Body </b>: </td>
        <td><textarea name="body" rows="10" columns="50"></textarea>     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center">
        <input type="submit" value=" SAVE "/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

EmailMessage.java

```
package com.qburst.templateemail.entity;

public class EmailMessage {

private String category;
private String subject;
private String body;
private Long id;

public String getCategory() {
    return category;
}

public void setCategory(String category) {
    this.category = category;
}

public String getSubject() {
    return subject;
}

public void setSubject(String subject) {
    this.subject = subject;
}

public String getBody() {
    return body;
}

public void setBody(String body) {
    this.body = body;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

}
```

template.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Template Webpage</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>select</th>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Subject</th>
        <th>Body</th>
      </tr>
      <c:forEach var="emailMessage" items="${emailMessageList}">
          <tr>
            <td><label for="${emailMessage.id}"></label><input type="radio" name="emailMsg" id="${emailMessage.id}"/></td>
            <td>${emailMessage.category}</td>
            <td>${emailMessage.subject}</td>
            <td>${emailMessage.body}</td>
          </tr>
      </c:forEach>
    </table><br>
    <input type="button" onclick="location.href='/TemplateEmail/email'" value="Add More" />
    <br><br><br>
    <input type="button" onclick="location.href='/TemplateEmail/send_email'" value="Send To" />
    </center>
  </body>
</html>
```

EmailDao.java
This is the code for fetching the list from database.

```
public List<EmailMessage> fetchTemplate() {
    String query = "select * from email_message";
    Connection connection = null;
    List<EmailMessage> emailMessageList = new ArrayList<EmailMessage>();
    try {
        EmailMessage emailMessage = new EmailMessage();
        connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery(query);
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            emailMessage.setCategory(resultSet.getString("category"));
            emailMessage.setSubject(resultSet.getString("subject"));
            emailMessage.setBody(resultSet.getString("body"));
            emailMessageList.add(emailMessage);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return emailMessageList;
}
```

Comment: You are displaying in your view the "emailMessageList" what's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, try to create always new object at the loop:

```
EmailMessage emailMessage;
while (resultSet.next()) {
       emailMessage = new EmailMessage();
       emailMessage.setCategory(resultSet.getString("category"));
       emailMessage.setSubject(resultSet.getString("subject"));
       emailMessage.setBody(resultSet.getString("body"));
       emailMessageList.add(emailMessage);
}
```

You are added repeated link at object to list. You always change values at the all members of list, because it link to one object.